# how can I change the admin url?

Tags: 6, security, uri

Is it possible to have the administration pages on a different place than /admin?

so something like: www.mysite.com/someotheradminlocation

I don't want the admin location to be guessable by hackers.

Comment: Knowing the URL for the administration pages is not a security issue in itself, and it should never be.

Comment: Security through obscurity is a waste of time, you should concentrate your efforts elsewhere. Enforce a strong password policy for administrators and make sure your permissions are set up correctly, keep up to date with security updates for core and contrib modules, etc

Comment: You can look at using [two factor authentications](http://groups.drupal.org/node/235938) to make log in more secure

Comment: I was just looking for an additional security method. After the site has been 'hacked'/'defaced' for 2 times in 2 month, I thought having the admin page hidden might add to making it more secure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be very easy. It's under Site building > URL aliases > Add alias (admin/build/path/add)
You can add a new URL alias there.

So if you can't find it you might need to install the pathauto module

**solution 2**

If you are using Drupal 6, you can get the same feature by using the following code in your settings.php file.

```
function custom_url_rewrite_outbound(&$path, &$options, $original_path) {
    if (preg_match('|^admin(?![^/])(.*)|', $path, $matches)) {
        $path = 'backend'. $matches[1];
    }
}

function custom_url_rewrite_inbound(&$result, $path, $path_language) {
    if (preg_match('|^backend(?![^/])(.*)|', $path, $matches)) {
        $result = 'admin'. $matches[1];
    }
    if (preg_match('|^admin(?![^/])(.*)|', $path, $matches)) {
        $result = '404'. $matches[1];
    }
}
```

Comment: But by using outbound function will it not change admin -> new admin path and yet still allow a user to access new admin page  when you type in admin ?

Comment: The preferred solution should make the admin path unguessable.

Comment: The "solution 2" makes sense to me. @Toad, just replace "backend" with your unguessable string and it should work.

Answer (score 3):

There is a module to do what monymirza suggested - http://drupal.org/project/rename_admin_paths

> The purpose of this module is to secure drupal backend by overriding
>   admin path.

Comment: This module is only for D7, OP tagged the question with D6.

Comment: Good point, Nikhil, though the project page does give some advice for Drupal 6.